# Roblox Studio [Plugin Script] - Cloned trees are wrongly rotated

Tags: lua, model, roblox, spawn

I would like to write in advance that I wanted to describe my problem on the Roblox Developers site but unfortunately I can't post new topics there yet as I am a new Roblox Studio user with very little experience in Unity 3D. Apart from that I know Java, Kotlin and C# reasonably well.

[A video showing the problem (Streamable)](https://streamable.com/8f579t)

I have written a **Plugin** script that randomly selects a tree model from 'ReplicatedStorage/Trees', then clones it and places it at the click point in the 3D world (in Roblox Studio Editor, not in game). The problem seems to be that the trees are not positioned straight - in the video I showed, the trees do not clone straight (up) even on Flat Terrain. I have tried:

- Set the CFrame Angles to 0, 90 or 180 etc (I checked all axis) but trees are still not rotated in up direction...

```lua
local rotation = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0), math.rad(0), math.rad(0))
SpawnedTree:PivotTo(position * rotation)
```

- Just set position:

```lua
SpawnedTree:PivotTo(position)
```

**AND!** I use a tree model named [Pine Tree](https://create.roblox.com/marketplace/asset/183435411/Pine-Tree) - Pivot is in right place, Orientation and Position is set to `(0, 0, 0)`

Entire script (not localscript) located in `workspace` without GUI code:

```lua
local NO_TREES_FOUND_ERROR = "No trees found!"
local NO_TREES_FOLDER_FOUND_ERROR = "No 'Trees' folder found!"

-- Tag Log
local TAG = "TPlace: "

-- Spawn tree
local function spawnTree(position)
    local treeToSpawn = nil -- Final Tree Model to spawn
    local randomInt -- Number of model to pick
    local storage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage") -- Obvious

    if not storage:FindFirstChild("Trees") then -- Just check if 'Trees' folder exist
        showError(NO_TREES_FOUND_ERROR) -- In GUI
        warn(TAG .. "No 'Trees' folder found! Create this folder in ReplicatedStorage and place trees there!")
    else
        local children = storage.Trees:GetChildren()
        
        if #children == 0 then -- If 'Trees' folder exist, check if there is tree models
            showError(NO_TREES_FOUND_ERROR) -- In GUI
            warn(TAG .. "No trees found! They need to be in ReplicatedStorage/Trees")
        else
            if #children == 1 then -- If there is only one model, select '1'
                randomInt = 1
            else
                local randomInt = math.random(1, #children)
            end

            treeToSpawn = children[randomInt]

            local SpawnedTree = treeToSpawn:Clone() -- Clone Tree
            SpawnedTree.Parent = workspace -- Add to workspace

            local rotation = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0), math.rad(0), math.rad(0)) -- Set rotation (does'nt work)

            SpawnedTree:PivotTo(position * rotation) -- Transform
        end
    end
end

-- Get Mouse click positions
local Mouse = plugin:GetMouse()

local target = nil

local function button1Down()
    target = Mouse.Target
end

local function button1Up()
    if target == Mouse.Target and target.Name == "Terrain" then
        spawnTree(Mouse.Hit)
    end
end

local ClickEventDown
local ClickEventUp
ClickEventDown = Mouse.Button1Down:Connect(button1Down)
ClickEventUp = Mouse.Button1Up:Connect(button1Up)
plugin:Activate(isConnected)
```

**FIXED:**

Change:

```lua
local function button1Up()
    if target == Mouse.Target and target.Name == "Terrain" then
        spawnTree(Mouse.Hit) -- HERE
    end
end

local function spawnTree(position)
    [...]

    local rotation = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0), math.rad(0), math.rad(0))
    SpawnedTree:PivotTo(position * rotation)
end
```

To:

```lua
local function button1Up()
    if target == Mouse.Target and target.Name == "Terrain" then
        spawnTree(Mouse.Hit.Position) -- HERE
    end
end

local function spawnTree(position)
    [...]

    local rotation = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0), math.rad(0), math.rad(90)) -- Z to 90 bcs then the tree lies on the ground
    SpawnedTree:PivotTo(CFrame.new(position.x, position.y, position.z) * rotation)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to be careful about it that the [Mouse.Hit](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Mouse#Hit) object is a [CFrame](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/CFrame), not a Vector3. That means that it comes with positional *and* rotational information baked in. According to the documentation :

> The orientation of the Hit CFrame corresponds with the direction of the Mouse.UnitRay.

That means that the y-axis is likely not straight up, but based on the camera position and mouse position.

So if you want to strip away the rotation information, you can use the `.p` or `.Position` property of the CFrame to take just the positional information.

So try this :

```lua
local function button1Up()
    if target == Mouse.Target and target.Name == "Terrain" then
        spawnTree(Mouse.Hit.Position)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Now I'll know to look a little deeper (it bothers me a little that sometimes there are no hints for the code). I'll edit the post and add the solution there since the rotations still needed to be fixed anyway.